# Add a new column with a sortorder grouped on column but in original sort order

Tags: r, grouping, rank

I've got a dataset that I want to order in a certain way, I need it to be grouped by `CENTER`
but other than that the records must remain the same sort order as the original dataset. So VUMC is the first and KUL is second, so that should stay in the same order.

Admittedly I'm not as experienced in R, but in SQL (which I can't use here) I would just do a `DENSE_RANK` to get the desired result. In R there a base `rank` function, and the dplyr library has a `dense_rank` function, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

Here is the code I tried

```
df_results <- read.table(text = "
CENTER;FILE;HB;LineNr
VUMC;NPUT_00172.MRC;12.7;1
VUMC;PHYM_00577.MRC;11.9;2
VUMC;CPNU_00625.MRC;9.2;3
KUL;UYTC_00146.MRC;10.8;4
KUL;UKFA_00766.MRC;10.7;5
LOR;RFAF_00105.MRC;12.9;6
LOR;ARFW_00961.MRC;12.4;7
KUL;HMCU_00630.MRC;8.6;8
VUMC;FPRB_00509.MRC;10.8;9
LOR;TWUA_00651.MRC;10.6;10
", header = TRUE, sep = ";", na.strings = "")

library(dplyr)

df_results <- df_results %>%
  group_by(CENTER) %>%
  mutate(min_LineNr = min(LineNr),
     dense_linenr = rank(min_LineNr),
     NewSortOrder = (dense_linenr*1000 + LineNr) )
```

The `min(LineNr)` part works as expected, but the `rank` results in `2.0` and `2.5` which I can't quite explain.
I've also tried the `mutate(rank..)` as a separate statement, but that doesn't make any difference.
And I've also tried `dense_rank` which just results in all `1`'s for the new column, which again was not what I was expecting.

| CENTER | FILE | HB | LineNr | min_LineNr | dense_linenr | NewSortOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VUMC | NPUT_00172.MRC | 12.7 | 1 | 1 | 2.5 | 2501 |
| VUMC | PHYM_00577.MRC | 11.9 | 2 | 1 | 2.5 | 2502 |
| VUMC | CPNU_00625.MRC | 9.2 | 3 | 1 | 2.5 | 2503 |
| KUL | UYTC_00146.MRC | 10.8 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2004 |
| KUL | UKFA_00766.MRC | 10.7 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 2005 |
| LOR | RFAF_00105.MRC | 12.9 | 6 | 6 | 2 | 2006 |
| LOR | ARFW_00961.MRC | 12.4 | 7 | 6 | 2 | 2007 |
| KUL | HMCU_00630.MRC | 8.6 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 2008 |
| VUMC | FPRB_00509.MRC | 10.8 | 9 | 1 | 2.5 | 2509 |
| LOR | TWUA_00651.MRC | 10.6 | 10 | 6 | 2 | 2010 |

The desired result should ideally be like the table below, so NewSortOrder contains a sort order which is grouped by `CENTER` but within those centers it's sorted on the original lines order.

| CENTER | FILE | HB | LineNr | NewSortOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VUMC | NPUT_00172.MRC | 12.7 | 1 | 1001 |
| VUMC | PHYM_00577.MRC | 11.9 | 2 | 1002 |
| VUMC | CPNU_00625.MRC | 9.2 | 3 | 1003 |
| VUMC | FPRB_00509.MRC | 10.8 | 9 | 1004 |
| KUL | UYTC_00146.MRC | 10.8 | 4 | 2001 |
| KUL | UKFA_00766.MRC | 10.7 | 5 | 2002 |
| KUL | HMCU_00630.MRC | 8.6 | 8 | 2003 |
| LOR | RFAF_00105.MRC | 12.9 | 6 | 3001 |
| LOR | ARFW_00961.MRC | 12.4 | 7 | 3002 |
| LOR | TWUA_00651.MRC | 10.6 | 10 | 3003 |

My questions are:
Why do `rank` and `dense_rank` give these strange results? Why doesn't it do what it says on the tin, so to speak?
And what R code or library is the most straight forward way to get the desired resulting column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrange()` would be the desired method to sort rows of a data.frame. It arranges text values alphabeitally, but you can change this behavour by changing the column into a factor with levels in their natural order like so:

```r
df_results %>%
    mutate(CENTER=factor(CENTER,levels=unique(CENTER))) %>%
    group_by(CENTER) %>%
    mutate(NewSortOrder = as.numeric(CENTER) * 1000 + row_number()) %>%
    arrange(CENTER)
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   CENTER [3]
   CENTER FILE              HB LineNr NewSortOrder
   <fct>  <chr>          <dbl>  <int>        <dbl>
 1 VUMC   NPUT_00172.MRC  12.7      1         1001
 2 VUMC   PHYM_00577.MRC  11.9      2         1002
 3 VUMC   CPNU_00625.MRC   9.2      3         1003
 4 VUMC   FPRB_00509.MRC  10.8      9         1004
 5 KUL    UYTC_00146.MRC  10.8      4         2001
 6 KUL    UKFA_00766.MRC  10.7      5         2002
 7 KUL    HMCU_00630.MRC   8.6      8         2003
 8 LOR    RFAF_00105.MRC  12.9      6         3001
 9 LOR    ARFW_00961.MRC  12.4      7         3002
10 LOR    TWUA_00651.MRC  10.6     10         3003
```

Furthermore, `rank()` does exactly what it says it should do, consider:

```r
rank( c("B","A","C") ) # gives: 2 1 3
```

With ties (as in your case) it does the average. Consider for example your first group, `VUMC`, where min_lineNr is four 1's:

```
rank( c(1,1,1,1) ) # gives 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
```

4 different numbers would normaly receive ranks 1 2 3 4 (in some order). The default is to do the *average* of these ranks when there are ties, hence 2.5 (average of ranks c(1,2,3,4))

You can easily track and make sense of this behavour by trying various sized vectors of equal numbers:

```r
rank( 1 )          # 1
rank( c(1,1) )     # 1.5 1.5 (mean of c(1,2))
rank( c(1,1,1) )   # 2 2 2 (mean of c(1,2,3))
rank( c(1,1,1,1) ) # 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 (mean of c(1,2,3,4))
# etc.
```

The other strategies to deal with ties are given in [?rank](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rank)

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining, but then why didn't it change the column with min_colid `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6)` to a dense rank of `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)` ? Or how can I use `arrange()` to get that resulting column?

Comment: See the answer below with rleid for how to add min_colid as specified in your comment (note it requires the data.table package as well). Otherwise it's essentially just `as.numeric(as.factor( old_ids ))`

Comment: This answer works for me. If I understand correctly, you change the CENTER column to a `factor`, because that also **implicitly** applies a dense rank, and then use that as its numeric value. I gotta say though, I'm new to R and trying to figure out relatively basic operations is not very intuitive imho. Like, why doesn't base R rank() have a `dense` parameter?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow you. dense rank means that you would get eg. `[1,2,3,3,4]` instead of `[1,2,3,3,5]`, right? How does that affect how your rows are ordered? And did you actually need the column NewSortOrder or not?

Comment: I'm so used to SQL and I guess I was just expecting it to work the same way in R. But you're right, it doesn't matter for the actual sort order.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the `rleid` to get the dense rank as below

```r
df_results %>% arrange(factor(CENTER,levels=unique(CENTER))) %>% 
  mutate(dense=data.table::rleid(CENTER))


   CENTER           FILE   HB LineNr dense
1    VUMC NPUT_00172.MRC 12.7      1     1
2    VUMC PHYM_00577.MRC 11.9      2     1
3    VUMC CPNU_00625.MRC  9.2      3     1
4    VUMC FPRB_00509.MRC 10.8      9     1
5     KUL UYTC_00146.MRC 10.8      4     2
6     KUL UKFA_00766.MRC 10.7      5     2
7     KUL HMCU_00630.MRC  8.6      8     2
8     LOR RFAF_00105.MRC 12.9      6     3
9     LOR ARFW_00961.MRC 12.4      7     3
10    LOR TWUA_00651.MRC 10.6     10     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options for group (`CENTER`) ID:

1. Use `dense_rank()`
2. Use `cur_group_id()`

Then `row_number()` to enumerate the rows within each group.

Just need to let R know that you want the values of `CENTER` to sort in the order they appear in the data, which can be done with `forcats::fct_inorder()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# option 1
opt1 <- df_results |> 
  mutate(CENTER = fct_inorder(CENTER),
         grp_index = dense_rank(CENTER)) |> 
  group_by(CENTER) |> 
  mutate(row_index = row_number(),
         new_sort_order = grp_index * 1000 + row_index) |> 
  arrange(CENTER)

# option 2
opt2 <- df_results |> 
  mutate(CENTER = fct_inorder(CENTER)) |> 
  group_by(CENTER) |> 
  mutate(grp_index = cur_group_id(),
         row_index = row_number(),
         new_sort_order = grp_index * 1000 + row_index) |> 
  arrange(CENTER)

assertthat::are_equal(opt1, opt2) # TRUE
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
# Groups:   CENTER [3]
   CENTER FILE              HB LineNr grp_index row_index new_sort_order
   <fct>  <chr>          <dbl>  <int>     <int>     <int>          <dbl>
 1 VUMC   NPUT_00172.MRC  12.7      1         1         1           1001
 2 VUMC   PHYM_00577.MRC  11.9      2         1         2           1002
 3 VUMC   CPNU_00625.MRC   9.2      3         1         3           1003
 4 VUMC   FPRB_00509.MRC  10.8      9         1         4           1004
 5 KUL    UYTC_00146.MRC  10.8      4         2         1           2001
 6 KUL    UKFA_00766.MRC  10.7      5         2         2           2002
 7 KUL    HMCU_00630.MRC   8.6      8         2         3           2003
 8 LOR    RFAF_00105.MRC  12.9      6         3         1           3001
 9 LOR    ARFW_00961.MRC  12.4      7         3         2           3002
10 LOR    TWUA_00651.MRC  10.6     10         3         3           3003
```

Notes:

- We don't really need `arrange()` at the end, it's just cosmetic.
- Add `ungroup()` to remove the grouping factor from the data if needed.